# ggplot fit with image in the background for R Markdown

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a special chart based on ggplot to be exposed with R Markdown in a flexdashboard. The plot should be right sized and positioned over a background picture. I'm struggling to find the best way to do so as the fitting of the ggplot keep moving over the background.

Any idea to fit the background with the ggplot?

[Background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoco2.png)

[Output from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50qeQ.png)

```
pu <- 2
ma <- 3
op <- 2
inf <- 1
me <- 2
be <- 3


img0 <- readPNG("bkgDomainsActivation.png")

myChart <- ggplotGrob(
  ggplot() + theme_no_axes() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA),)+ coord_fixed()+
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.91, r = 1, start = 0, end = pi/2*pu), fill="#F4B183", color="#F4B183") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.81, r = 0.89, start = 0, end = pi/2*ma), fill="#A9D18E", color="#A9D18E") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.71, r = 0.79, start = 0, end = pi/2*op), fill="#8FAADC", color="#8FAADC") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.61, r = 0.69, start = 0, end = pi/2*inf), fill="#FCD965", color="#FCD965") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.51, r = 0.59, start = 0, end = pi/2*be), fill="#47B1F2", color="#47B1F2") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.41, r = 0.49, start = 0, end = pi/2*me), fill="#8295AE", color="#8295AE")+
  
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.91, r = 1, start = pi/2*pu, end = pi/2), fill="transparent", color="transparent") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.81, r = 0.89, start = pi/2*ma, end = pi/2), fill="transparent", color="transparent") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.71, r = 0.79, start = pi/2*op, end = pi/2), fill="transparent", color="transparent") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.61, r = 0.69, start = pi/2*inf, end = pi/2), fill="transparent", color="transparent") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.51, r = 0.59, start = pi/2*be, end = pi/2), fill="transparent", color="transparent") +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.41, r = 0.49, start = pi/2*me, end = pi/2), fill="transparent", color="transparent")
  )
  
myPlot <- ggdraw() + draw_image(img0) + draw_plot(myChart, scale = 0.395, x=.243, y=.047)
ggsave("myPlot.png")
include_graphics("myPlot.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to align them if you're working in a raster space, ie with a rendered output of the chart with fixed dimensions. I'm using manually-adjusted magic numbers for the output and composition to make them align.

e.g.

```
library(magick)
library(grid); library(ggplot2); library(ggforce)
img0 <- image_read("xoco2.png")
myChart <- ggplot() + theme_no_axes() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA),)+ coord_fixed()+
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.91, r = 1, start = 0, end = pi/8*pu), fill="#F4B183", color="#F4B183") +
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.81, r = 0.89, start = 0, end = pi/8*ma), fill="#A9D18E", color="#A9D18E") +
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.71, r = 0.79, start = 0, end = pi/8*op), fill="#8FAADC", color="#8FAADC") +
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.61, r = 0.69, start = 0, end = pi/8*inf), fill="#FCD965", color="#FCD965") +
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.51, r = 0.59, start = 0, end = pi/8*be), fill="#47B1F2", color="#47B1F2") +
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.41, r = 0.49, start = 0, end = pi/8*me), fill="#8295AE", color="#8295AE")
fig <- image_graph(width = 600, height = 562)
myChart
dev.off()
image_composite(img0, fig, offset = "+1015+52", operator = "multiply")
```

[image]

Comment: @XavierBronlet Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if the solution works for you